# Notification system to alert the user

Tags: php, notifications, sms

I would like to to have a notification system to alert the user via Google SMS system and register user with their phone number. I would like to send the alert when certain condition is reached in a PHP web application. Would it be possible? Could you please give some suggestion?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. There are apis available for this functionality. You could implement this yourself and you can send text messages via email if you use an api to figure out the phone carrier of the user.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I am sorry to ask again, but, I do not know about APIs available for this functionality. Could you please give some references for this?

Comment: Check out [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/notify/pricing) They offer very good prices. They give you 10,000 free sms per month and after that they charge $0.00025 per message.